# Calculating diameter of a polygon with sf package

Tags: r, r-sf

I have an `sf` object in R representing a county, and I'd like to calculate its diameter. That is, I want to know the maximum distance between any two points on its boundary. How do I do that in R?

I know that in principle, one can use the rotating calipers method applied to the convex hull of the county. Is there an R function for that? I've seen a suggestion to take the diameter of the minimum bounding circle, but that's only a rough approximation to the method of taking the diameter of the convex hull.

Below is an example based on Louisville, Kentucky. The following plot shows the county and its convex hull as determined by the `lwgeom` package.

[image]

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

# Set plotting theme ----
  theme_set(theme_minimal() +
              theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
                    plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
                    panel.grid = NULL))

# Download data ----
  louisville_ky <- tigris::counties(state = "KY", year = 2019) %>%
    filter(COUNTYFP == "111")
  
  lou_convex_hull <- st_convex_hull(louisville_ky)

# Plot the data ----
    ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = louisville_ky,
            color = 'dodgerblue4', fill = 'dodgerblue4') +
    geom_sf(data = lou_convex_hull,
            color = "white", fill = NA, size = 2)
```

Comment: The rotating calipers method may have been implemented in the `flightplanning::getMinBBox()`. [PDF here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flightplanning/flightplanning.pdf) and the [github source code](https://github.com/caiohamamura/flightplanning-R/blob/master/R/utils.R).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cast the convex hull to MULTIPOINT, then POINT, use `st_distance`, and keep only the maximum distance:

```
lou_convex_hull %>%
  st_cast('MULTIPOINT') %>%
  st_cast('POINT') %>%
  st_distance() %>%
  max()

55462.84 [m]
```

Looks like it's the same without bothering to use the convex hull:

```
louisville_ky %>% 
 st_cast('MULTIPOINT') %>% 
 st_cast('POINT') %>% 
 st_distance %>% 
 max()

55462.84 [m]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method isn't very efficient, but it works. This simply calculates the distance among all of the points in the convex set and then determines which two points have the maximum distance. The `st_length()` function is then used to calculate the distance of those points in the appropriate units.

```
# Get the points in the convex set
ch_points <- st_coordinates(lou_convex_hull)[,c("X", "Y")]

# Find the most distant points
dist_matrix <- as.matrix(dist(ch_points)) 
max_inds <- arrayInd(which.max(dist_matrix), dim(dist_matrix))
most_distant_points <- ch_points[as.vector(max_inds),]

# Calculate their distance
distance <- st_linestring(most_distant_points, dim = "XY") %>%
  st_sfc(crs = st_crs(lou_convex_hull)) %>%
  st_length()

print(distance)
#> 55462.51 [m]
```